# does not conform to protocol Swift Parent Class - Objective C Protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I am trying to call my Protocol Class in Swift, but its giving me Error

> "Type SwiftViewController does not conform to protocol ABCDelegate.

Could you please tell me what I am missing , as I find other posts , but nothing is explained properly , also let me know if you need more info.

```
@protocol ABCDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) ABC:(NSString*)MessageResponseStr
@end
@interface ABC : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ABCDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *ResponseStr;
-(void)Network:(int)NetworkState
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A protocol defines abstract behaviour.

Like interface in many other languages. `ABCDelegate`protocol simply states: Anything that will implement me, need to specify the following required methods, and can choose to implement the following optional methods.

In your case, your class need to implement the protocol required `ABC` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined the protocol in `ABC` class, you declared the protocol method to be `@required` as in -

```
@protocol ABCDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) ABC:(NSString*)MessageResponseStr
@end
```

Now in `SwiftViewController` or any class that implements the protocol, it has become mandatory to add the `- (void) ABC:(NSString*)MessageResponseStr` because of the `@required` keyword.

As soon as you implement the method, error will go away.

Hope this helped.